# How do I programmatically attach a file to a file field in a node?

Tags: 8, forms, files

I have a custom content type with a file field. I am trying to attach a file uploaded through a custom form to the custom content type. I am able to load the node and update all the other values of the node except the file field.

I found [Realityloop: Programmatically attach files to a node in Drupal 8](https://mzlizz.mit.edu/realityloop-programmatically-attach-files-node-drupal-8),  but it doesn't seem to work.

This was what was suggested in the above link

```
$node = Node::create([
  'type' => 'article',
  'title' => 'Druplicon test',
  'field_image' => [
  'target_id' => $file->id(),
  ],
]);
$node->save();
```

This is what I have tried inside `submitForm`

```
$fid = $form_state->getValue('file_field_name')[0];
$file = File::load($fid);
$file->setPermanent();
$file->save();
$node = Node::load($nid);     
$node->set('file_field_in_node', $file->id);
$node->save();
```

That was setting the file as permanent in the files table but the node did not have the file.

I also tried to save with

```
$node->set('file_field_in_node', $file);
```

That did not help either. I am also curious as to which is the file/function that handles the set function for the file field.

**UPDATE:**

[SOLVED] Not sure what was wrong earlier. Both the approaches seems to be working correctly now. So setting the file_id or the file object into the file field for the node seem to be saving the node correctly with the file attached to it.

Comment: Are you usign core's Media module to manage your files?

Comment: No. I added a file field to a content entity. I am using a custom form to collect data for the entity and am creating and saving the entity on form submit. I am not using any other modules / APIs so far.

Comment: Since this question seems to be about code, we need to see the code you wrote. Without that, we cannot tell you what is wrong in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I have updated the code. I was also able to get this working. I will update the question with the solution as well.

Comment: Not sure how to restructure the question to document the answer / question correctly so that this will help somebody. Inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use media core module to manage files, you have already uploaded your file, and you want to attached it to filed eg `field_file`

```
    $node = Node::load(NID);
    $node->set('field_file' , ['target_id' => FID]);
    $node->save();
```

Note: `FID` is your file id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @berramou. I am not using the media module. I am only looking to attach files to a content type and keep it in the system. Not sure if I need to use the media module.

Comment: BTW this automatically takes care of file_usage or do we have to do that explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

In your custom form use code like this:

```
$form['imagefile'] = [
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => $this->t('Imagefile'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['imagefile'],
      '#weight' => '0',
      '#upload_location' => 'public://images/redaktion/',
    ];
```

And here's a piece of code how it works low level:

```
// check if the folder exists
$folder = date('Y-m', time());
$data = file_get_contents($imagefilepath);
if (!is_dir("/home/rainer/src/asdent/web/sites/default/files/images/pics/{$folder}")) {
      mkdir("/home/rainer/src/asdent/web/sites/default/files/images/pics/{$folder}");
}
// create the file entity
$photo = file_save_data($data, "public://images/pics/{$folder}/".$filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

// later in your entity::create:
'myimage' => ['target_id' => $photo->id()],
```

The trick is to create the file entity beforehand and then link the custom entity to it.

Comment: Sorry, this is very basic. If you're using D8 standard form API with a '#type' => 'managed_file' there should not be any problem.

Comment: Thanks for input Rainer Feike. I was able to get this working.